# using nhibernate sessionfactories in multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to uses `Isessions` from nhibernate over multiple Threads.
I read [here](http://thehelios.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/tutorial-on-nhibernate-and-fluentnhibernate/) how to instanciate a factory and it should be threadsafe.
I know ISession is not threadsafe, but I am intending of using only one ISession per thread.

Doing this doesnt work:

```
[Test]
public void TestMultipleThreads(){
  object id;
  using(var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()){
   id = session.Save(new SomeThing("SomeText"));
  };
  Parallel.For(0,2,() =>{
    using (var session =NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()){
       using (var tx=session.BeginTransaction()){
        var something = session.Load<SomeThing>(id);
        Console.WriteLine(something.Text);
      };
    };
  });
}
```

I cant get that test to running, so that it will print out 2 Names. I am using SQLite and a memory database. What do I miss?

If this is not working, how Should I tell different Threads to use their own session?

**EDIT**

I get the message from the First Thread and the second throws an exception with Table not Found.

**EDIT 2**

I think the Prolem lies with the creation of the database.
When I create the new Table with a new created session, my other session doesnt know about the other session. But I'll try with an other database.

```
new SchemaExport(config).Execute(true,true,false,session.Connection,null);
```

Comment: Your code is legimate. It should be related to sqlite. Try with another DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you are using SQLite in memory database, 
usually it cease to exist when you close the connection,

in this example, it seems like your database is destroyed when you dispose the first session, along with the data you have persisted.